# If you use your own synchronisation can you the same command pool from different threads right?

Tags: vulkan

In Vulkan you're not supposed to call functions on a command pool from multiple threads, and the same goes for descriptor pools, right? I have made it so my different threads each have a separate command pool to allocate command buffers from, however I've decided that in the case of descriptors, instead of having one descriptor pool per thread, the way I did with the command pools, that I could instead lock a mutex each time I need to get a descriptor set from a pool. I really don't call these functions very often, and locking the mutex may be a good way.

Comment: A better question is why you're creating descriptors like that to begin with. Maybe you can restructure your rendering so that this is not needed.

Comment: There seems to be some typo in the title. Can you please edit it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In Vulkan you're not supposed to call functions on a command pool from multiple threads, and the same goes for descriptor pools, right?

The rule is that "Host access to `object X` must be externally synchronized," where `object X` is (among other things) a pool. How you do that is entirely up to you.

One way to ensure synchronization is to only access those pools from a specific thread. But Vulkan doesn't care how you establish external synchronization, so long as you do.

Comment: What does "externally synchronised" mean? Internally synchronised means the API does the synchronisation for you and "external synchronisation" means synchronisation that YOU do, that the API doesn't do, meaning OUTSIDE of the API? When I look up the term internal and external synchronisation all the results are about synchronising clocks.

Comment: @Zebrafish: "*When I look up the term internal and external synchronisation all the results are about synchronising clocks.*" Did you try looking it up in the Vulkan specification?

Comment: Yes, it basically looks like it means you have to do synchronisation, the API doesn't do it. How many pages is the spec anyway? Seems enormous.